# What are the benefits to adding a bitcoin blockhash UID notation to one's OpenPGP key?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature, identity, bitcoin, openpgp

Example:

> Notation data: blockhash@bitcoin.org 000000000000000011d9f6931e65f814c6f3b221736b0c45f25e0365a3d156fa

As seen here: https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x7FAB114267E4FA04

In case you are not familiar with bitcoin, the "blockhash" above refers to [a particular block of transactions](https://blockchain.info/block/000000000000000011d9f6931e65f814c6f3b221736b0c45f25e0365a3d156fa) which was mined on the same day the PGP key was created: `2013-10-19 07:11:32`

Does this establish a minimum age of the UID?  Or some other benefit?

Comment: The OpenPGP key does not only provide a blockhash reference, but also regular mail address user IDs. What about a simply inquire to the key's owner?

Comment: Great question. What the heck is going on here? As far as I can tell, that's an ID for [this block in the blockchain](https://blockchain.info/block-index/326983/000000000000000011d9f6931e65f814c6f3b221736b0c45f25e0365a3d156fa). How on earth is that related to <pete@petertodd.org> ?? Does one of those transactions include the pgp key?

Comment: I added more info about bitcoin block hash and the fact that it is on the same date as the key was created.  Also saw that @jens-erat signed this particular key... Hmm...  ;-)

Comment: Did you email the key holder (Peter Todd), or can I?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I'll go ahead and email Peter Todd to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Peter Todd directly, this is his response:

> Basically, you guys are quite right to recognise that this *isn't* timestamping a PGP signature, but rather weakly proving the signature was created after a certain point in time. But that's a rather weak proof, as what exactly prevents you from recreating the signature with a different blockhash? Not much! Hard to come up with a threat model.
>
>
> OTOH, I am timestamping **Bitcoin itself**... and I'm such a trustworthy guy obviously that adds significant confidence to the timestamping Bitcoin provides, above and beyond the hundreds of millions of dollars of electricity burned by miners.
>
>
> tl;dr: It's a _really_ nerdy joke. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for coming back and posting! I am amused.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question, I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that it's a proof of age that the PGP key is newer than `2013-10-19`. My reasoning is as follows:

What makes blockchain mining computationally hard is fiddling with the nonce until the hash of that block has a specific number of leading zeros (16 hex zeros, or 64 binary zeros in this case). Once you find such a nonce for that block of transactions, you can publish the block and claim the bitcoin mining reward.

That hash is 64 hex digits = 32 bytes, or 256 bits. Currently there are 410086 block in the blockchain. That means the chances of guessing a random 192 bit hex value (256 - 64 bits of leading zeros) and having it match the hash of an existing block is about 1 / 10^52. So the fact that he embedded in his key the hash of a block from `2013-10-19` means that this block had already been published by the time he published his key; but there's nothing to stop him from having inserted that retro-actively.

**In summary: this proves that the key was published sometime between 2013-10-19 and now**.

I also notice that the key was first self-signed on `2012-04-25`, but the blockhash wasn't added until `2013-10-19` and then the same blockhash has been carried forward ever since. I'm a little stumped to as to what that's proving. Why would you want to prove that you key is newer than a certain time?

If you want a definitive answer, then email him! I'm sure a bitcoin / PGP nerd would be happy to explain!

Comment: @JonathanCross By the way, if you do email him, please post the answer here, or I will email him!

Comment: Yes, I'll be sure to add any info here.

Comment: FYI: Response was added above.